# Phing pdosqlexec Segmentation Fault

Tags: mysql, database, dump, phing

when i try to execute this

```
<pdosqlexec 
    url="${pdo_driver}:host=${host};dbname=${db.name};" 
    userid="${mysql_user}" 
    password="${mysql_pwd}" 
    encoding="utf8" 
    onerror="abort">
    <fileset dir="./cache/mysql/">
        <include name="dump.sql"/>
    </fileset>
    <formatter type="plain" outfile="./cache/mysql/output4.txt"/>
</pdosqlexec>
```

i get a segmentation fault, and the loading of the dump.sql is interrupted.
Any solution?

Comment: what did you do to debug the problem?

Comment: actually i don't know what to do to debug the problem..

Comment: Use a smaller dump file, use no dump file, change encoding, change password, write some plain php code that does the same as the phing code and see where it fails by removing/commenting lines out. Also, update PHP to the latest version. This will most likely fix the problem.

Comment: what i've noticed is that with small dump files it never triggers the Segmentation fault error (talking about less then 4MB dump) but my dump are much bigger.. and it is a problem if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can try add **delimitertype="row"** option to **pdosqlexec**. For me this solution helps load files larger then 4 MB

full example of use

```
<pdosqlexec
    url="mysql:host=${DB_HOST};dbname=${DB_NAME}"
    userid="${DB_USER}"
    password="${DB_PASS}"
    delimitertype="row">
        <transaction src="${DB_SCHEMA_PATH}/notus-backend.sql"/>
        <formatter type="plain" outfile="${LOG_PATH}/phing.CreateTables.log"/>
</pdosqlexec>
```